# Erro que encerra o serviço java android

Tags: java, android

Tenho um serviço rodando em background que se encerra depois de um tempo após fechar o app. Eu não quero que o serviço se encerre ao fecha o app

Serviço:

```
public class GpsService  extends Service {
public static final String BROADCAST_ACTION = "com.emersonbarcellos.mototaxi.displayevent";
private final Handler handler = new Handler();
Intent intent;
int counter = 30;
String chamado=null;
private Controller aController = null;

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);  
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);
    handler.postDelayed(sendUpdatesToUI, 1000); // 1 second

}
@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId){
    super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);

    Bundle b = intent.getExtras();
    chamado = b.get("ID_CHAMADO").toString();
    return startId;
}

private Runnable sendUpdatesToUI = new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        DisplayLoggingInfo();           
        handler.postDelayed(this, 10000); // 30 seconds
    }
};    

private void DisplayLoggingInfo() {

    new LeitoraDeCoordenadas(this);
}

private void tentativa(String lat, String lon){
      final HttpPost Online = new HttpPost("http://fabianrepresentacoes.com.br/gcm/server.php?tipo=update_cordenadas&id="+chamado+"&latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lon);

      final HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
        Log.v("aviso", "http://fabianrepresentacoes.com.br/gcm/server.php?tipo=update_cordenadas&id="+chamado+"&latitude="+lat+"&longitude="+lon);
        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {

        try {

           HttpResponse responsePOST = client.execute(Online);  
           String responseBody = EntityUtils.toString(responsePOST.getEntity());

           Log.v("aviso", "Resposta " + responseBody);


        } catch (Exception e) {
            // TODO: handle exception

        }


            }}).start();

    }
private boolean isMyServiceRunning(Class<?> serviceClass) {
    ActivityManager manager = (ActivityManager) getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE);
    for (RunningServiceInfo service : manager.getRunningServices(Integer.MAX_VALUE)) {
        if (serviceClass.getName().equals(service.service.getClassName())) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}
@Override
public void onDestroy() {       
    handler.removeCallbacks(sendUpdatesToUI);

    super.onDestroy();
}   

public class LeitoraDeCoordenadas implements LocationListener {

    public LeitoraDeCoordenadas(Context context) {
        LocationManager manager = (LocationManager) context.getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        manager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 50, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        double latitude = location.getLatitude();
        double longitude = location.getLongitude();
        String Lat = String.valueOf(latitude);
        String Lon = String.valueOf(longitude);
        Log.i("aviso", Lat);
        Log.i("aviso", Lon);
      tentativa(Lat, Lon);
    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    }


}}
```

LogCat:

```
03-11 13:00:29.832: E/test(17688): Exception
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688): Process: com.emersonbarcellos.mototaxi, PID: 17688
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to     start service com.emersonbarcellos.mototaxi.GpsService@41a5d2b8 with null: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2814)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2100(ActivityThread.java:145)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1362)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5214)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:814)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:630)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at com.emersonbarcellos.mototaxi.GpsService.onStartCommand(GpsService.java:48)
03-11 13:00:29.852: E/AndroidRuntime(17688):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleServiceArgs(ActivityThread.java:2797)
```

Comment: Qual é a linha 48...?

Comment: eu editei a pergunta, Cara a verdade é que eu não sei onde está/acontece o erro que faz com que ele se encerre quando não estou com a aplicação aberta

Comment: Talvez o `b.get("ID_CHAMADO")` esteja retornando *null*.

Comment: (Não posso comentar por isso escrevo aqui). Utiliza o Log.d("DEBUG","No Oncreate"), por exemplo, para saber onde é que estás a obter o erro, assim é mais facil saber onde tas a obter a excepção. Possivelmente será aqui: `intent = new Intent(BROADCAST_ACTION);`

Comment: A pergunta está mal formulada, dá a entender que você quer que o serviço não possa ser removido da memória pelo Android. Uma solução para este problema seria iniciar o serviço com startForeground(), mantendo uma notificação "permanente". O problema desta pergunta é simplesmente um bug.